# Problem related to a complex matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am stuck on the  following problem:

> Let $P$ be a $2 \times 2$ complex matrix such that trace $P=1$ and $\det P=-6.$ Then
>     trace $(P^4-P^3)=?$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate out the eigenvalues of $P$ are $-2$ and $3$. Then $$tr(P^4-P^3)=tr(P^4)-tr(P^3)=\Big((-2)^4+3^4\Big)-\Big((-2)^3+3^3\Big)$$